# Universal Analytics Events (except for fired locally) are not showing up in GA Event Reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

All of my event tags are firing in Preview Mode but only showing up in GA Reports when fired locally by me.
Rather than repost the message and relevant documentation, please refer to this link on Google Tag Manager Product forums where it was initially listed. Unfortunately I have not received any feedback on it.
Thanks in advance for having a look.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/CnWt1OUfwG8;context-place=forum/tag-manager

Comment: Are you using GA 360 or free? If free, give some time the data will show up. Please make sure, you have not placed any filters in the GA view, that may restrict the inflow of traffic into your GA

Comment: I am using the Free version.  Yes, originally I was wondering why nothing at all was showing up in GA Reports. But GA Reports has been showing the local songplays initiated by me since Oct 4th.

Comment: Here is what I have in my View Settings:   Basic Settings, View ID - 161285732. View Name - All Web Site Data.
Website's URL - http://www.dandepolito.com. Time zone country or territory - United States , GMT 04:00 Eastern time, Default page optional - blank. Exclude URL Query Parameters optional - blank,         
Currency displayed as - US Dollar (USD $), Bot Filtering -> Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders  - unchecked, Site Search Settings -> Site search Tracking optional - OFF

Comment: Have you published a container?

Comment: I am up to Live Version 26. Is there a restriction on the number of frequency that one is allowed to Publish if using the Free version of GA?  Obviously, something is being published or I would not see GA Report results for the songplays that I initiate from my local laptop and/or Mobile table.  thx.